# Add Zeppelin visu to an existing Spark Streming application

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, data-visualization, apache-zeppelin

I'd like to know if there's a way to connect zeppelin directly to a spark application without writting all the code in zepplin. All the examples I found on the web are doing this and I surprisingly wouldn't find someone using zepplin only for the visualization tools.
Am I missing something?

Thanks by advance!

Comment: Add your code/package to the interpreter classpath. Import the necessary classes. Call the methods you need... That should work, in theory